# How to overcome limitation of ISNUMERIC column "ERROR : overflowed an int column"

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement wherein I have to check whether value entered in `VARCHAR(200)` column is numeric or not, and if so a relevant error message should be passed.

I am validating the same with `ISNUMERIC` function since my column value is `varchar` so user can enter more than 10 characters as well due to which I am getting this error:

> overflowed an int column

Because of the other business support, I can not change the data type of the column to `in`t.

As of now I have implemented `LEN() < 10` condition before checking `ISNUMERIC` but seeking if any alternate and better option available.

Comment: [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` should support more that 10 char long numbers.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers a question nobody has ever wanted to ask "can this string be converted to *any* of the numeric datatypes? (and I don't care which of those data types, nor should you tell me)"

Answer (score 1):

If you work on Sql server 2012 Than its better to Use **TRY_Convert()** Function.it will give **NULL** as output rather than  impose error

```
declare @d varchar(200)='940852774565564'
if ((select ISNUMERIC(@d))=1)
select Try_Convert(@d as bigint)
```

else 
Convert the value to **bigint** rather than **INT**

```
declare @d varchar(200)='940852774565564'
if ((select ISNUMERIC(@d))=1)
select cast(@d as bigint)
```